# R plot categorial changes - sankey diagram

Tags: r, categories, sankey-diagram

Does somebody know how to plot changes of two categorial variables in R?

Such as in this example:

http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/waehlerwanderung-in-hamburg-wer-wem-die-stimmen-stahl-1.2353382

(Without the dynamics)

So I have two categorial variables like: Pre and Post

Pre = sample(1:100,10000,replace=TRUE)

Post = sample(1:100,10000,replace=TRUE)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a so called sankey diagram:

```
set.seed(1)
(edgelist <- transform(subset(expand.grid(source = c("spd", "linke", "cdu"), target = c("spd ", "linke ", "cdu "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), target != paste0(source, " ")), value = sample(1:200, nrow(edgelist))))
#   source target value
# 2  linke   spd     54
# 3    cdu   spd     75
# 4    spd linke    114
# 6    cdu linke    179
# 7    spd   cdu     40
# 8  linke   cdu    176

require(rCharts)
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$setTemplate(script = "layouts/chart.html")
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey') 
sankeyPlot$set(data = edgelist, nodeWidth = 55, nodePadding = 50, width = 700, height = 400)
sankeyPlot
```

[image: sankey]

Comment: I added "sankey diagram" to the question title to make maybe it easier to find for somebody else. Great, it's really nice that R can do something like this

Comment: good idea. Yes, R can do so many things, but it's a bit of a maze sometimes... ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a very bare-bones, no-nonsense plot you can use the segments() function.

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(1,2), ylim=c(0,100))

segments(x0, Pre, x1, Post)
```